Unit Testing Springs WebClient with UriBuilder with Coverage
I have a pretty straightforwart GET call using Springs WebClient. The call looks like this:
webClient.get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .queryParam("param1", "value1")
            .queryParam("param2", "value2")
            .path("/appPath")
            .build()
      ).retrieve().bodyToMono(MyClass.class).block();

How can I unit test this method in regard to code coverage? When I mock the uriBuilder Function the unit test finishes with success but the coverage is lower than SonarQube wants it to be and therefore the Jenkins build fails.

Coverage is a really bad metric that can easily be gamed. @Test void test() { try { callYourMethod(); } catch (final Exception ex) {} now you 100% coverage

How do you generate the code coverage?

@Bademeister Wdym? Right click -> More Run/Debug -> Run 'MyTest' with Coverage

I use SonarCloud and generate the coverage with jacoco. A customisation for integration tests was necessary. The MockMvc tests were only included in the coverage after the jacoco configuration was customised. Maybe it is the same with the WebClient tests. https://natritmeyer.com/howto/reporting-aggregated-unit-and-integration-test-coverage-with-jacoco/
